# typeahead with restrictions using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have created a typeahead with some names and i want to remove all already used name.
TS:

```
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    filter(term => term.length >=1),
    map(term => this.coathangers.filter(coathangers => new RegExp(term, 'mi').test(coathangers.name)).slice(0, 20)),
  )
```

HTML:

```
 <label class="control-label" for="typeahead-basic">Kleiderbügel:              
              <input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform: capitalize"
                [(ngModel)]="coathanger" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [ngbTypeahead]="search"
                [inputFormatter]="formatter" [resultFormatter]="formatter"
                [editable]='false' class="field"/>
            </label>
```

i want to remove or disabled all names that have already a borrower. with something like that **if(user.hanher.name=== coathangers.name) then disavled** or whatever. but i don't how i can do it or how i can include a if-condition in **search =...** or direct in the html

Do someone have any idea?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, can you not use the filter function you already have to filter by the user name also?

Comment: i solved my problem thanks anyway